# Why assignment changes the precision of calculation of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, floating-accuracy

I am writing some scripts using MATLAB R2020a and I am having a problem: there are two values I want to assign to a vector `z_samples`, namely `x_samples(l_indexes)./sum(x_samples)`(a vector) and `x_samples(T_deno_index)./sum(x_samples) - 1`(a value) and they have a sum of 0 (here `x_samples` is a Gaussian vector from the function `mvnrnd` and `l_indexes` is an index vector which doesn't overlap the index `T_deno_index`. `l_indexes` and `T_deno_index` together cover all the elements in `x_samples`):

```
sum(x_samples(l_indexes)./sum(x_samples)) + x_samples(T_deno_index)./sum(x_samples) - 1 = 0
```

[image: picture: sum to zero]

however, when I assign them separately to the `z_samples`:

```
z_samples(l_indexes) = x_samples(l_indexes)./sum(x_samples);
z_samples(T_deno_index) = x_samples(T_deno_index)./sum(x_samples) - 1;
```

the sum of `z_samples` is not 0:

```matlab
>> sum(z_samples) 

ans = 
    
    -5.5511e-17
```

I want to know what is going on here and how can I fix this.

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Please post actual code, not pseudocode. Your line `sum(x_samples(l_indexes)./sum(x_samples)) + x_samples(T_deno_index)./sum(x_samples) - 1 = 0` is not valid MATLAB syntax, and doesn’t even represent the sum you say because parentheses are wrong. We also don’t know what is in all your variables. For example do `l_indexes` and `T_deno_index` overlap? Do they cover all elements of the array? You could simplify your example and give us a [mre] that we can actually run to reproduce your results—if we can reproduce them, we have all the information we might need to understand the problem.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, sorry for the confusion, I re-edited the post and because of the reputation I can't embed pictures in the post directly so I use the link instead. Hope now the post seems clear.

Comment: Remember, however, that if you are subtracting floating point values, -5.5e-17 **IS** zero.  You can't escape rounding errors.

Comment: @TimRoberts, thanks for your comment. The later program judges if the elements in z_samples sum to 0, so I'm wondering how to get the elements in z_samples to sum to 0 without changing the later program (theoretically this must hold true).

Comment: As Tim Roberts said, this all seems to be rooted in the (in)accuracy of floating point calculations, see  e.g. [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). If your later code requires the sum to be zero and you can't change that, a check for some lower limit at the end of your code might be one way to go.

Comment: Right.  Theoretically, real numbers have an infinite number of decimals places.  That's not true in the world of floating point.  Define an epsilon, and check for less than epsilon.

Comment: Thank you guys, I am now using a small epsilon instead.